# How can I update various sql columns based on another column of the same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am running SQL Server and am needing to update hundreds of entries.  Column A has unique values and based on that I need to update column B of the same table, all with different values.  Essentially I am looking for a way to perform the following but in a bulk manner:

```
UPDATE table
set column B = 'value'
where column A = 'unique value'
```

Comment: Do you have the replacement values in a separate table already (as key, value rows)?

Comment: Share some sample data and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are expecting,

```
UPDATE table
set column B = case when column A = 5 then 'unique string' end;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
update table set
columnB = concat('unique ', columnA)
```

you may, or may not, need a `where` clause, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With hundreds of values you better have the {unique value - update value} mapping defined in a separate table as TT is asking. But otherwise, if you are okay with hard-coding those mappings in your UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE t
SET B = CASE A
        WHEN 'unique value1' THEN 'value1'
        WHEN 'unique value2' THEN 'value2'
        WHEN 'unique value3' THEN 'value3'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END
FROM table t
```

BTW, the above is only for 3 mappings

Comment: Thanks TT and Tony.  I tried the following and getting syntax errors:

    UPDATE table
    SET statictext = CASE
    WHEN phonenumber = '1111111111' THEN 'Test 1'
    WHEN phonenumber = '2222222222' THEN 'Test 2'
    ELSE 'Error'
    END
    FROM table;

Comment: Whats the error you are getting? Also what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

### Here, you need to write cursor to update a column value in the same table

```
BEGIN 

    DECLARE c_a, c_b TEXT;

    DECLARE c_ab CURSOR FOR

    SELECT column_a,column_b FROM c_table;


   OPEN c_ab;

   LOOP 

   FETCH c_ab into c_ca, c_cb;

       IF c_ca = "0" THEN
        update c_table SET column_b = "No" WHERE 
        column_a = c_ca;
       END IF;

       IF c_ca = "1" THEN
        update c_table SET column_b = "Yes" WHERE 
        column_a = c_ca;
       END IF;

   END LOOP; 

   CLOSE c_ab; 
END
```

Working and tested code [please refer some cursor tutorials to update according to your condition] and with this you can update table in bulk and speedy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jim Macaulay. That did it.  Thank you everyone else for your input.